# Reference Placeholder from class file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've created a function in my vb class file that creates dynamic tables. I'm planning to use this to create tables dependent on a button being clicked. The function references a placeholder in my aspx page but I'm getting "placeHolder1 is not declared".

How can I access controls on my form from my class file?

Thanks

Class file snippet as follows:

```
Public Shared Function CreateTable() As Table
    'handle either total or breakdown
    Select Case format
        Case "breakdown"
            placePayDetails.Controls.Clear()
            Dim tblPayDetails As Table = New Table()
            placePayDetails.Controls.Add(tblPayDetails)
```

etc

Comment: Show the code. You are probably just forgetting to pass a reference from one side to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your updated version of the question, your `CreateTable` function needs to receive a `placePayDetails` (presumably of type ContentPlaceHolder) as parameter.

The page calling this function needs to have this place holder defined somewhere in the markup.

Example:

```
Public Shared Function CreateTable(byVal placePayDetails as ContentPlaceHolder) As Table
    'handle either total or breakdown
    Select Case format
        Case "breakdown"
            placePayDetails.Controls.Clear()
            Dim tblPayDetails As Table = New Table()
            placePayDetails.Controls.Add(tblPayDetails)
```

Answer (score 0):

the class file has no concept of your page. if you have a function in your class where you want the results of that function to return to the page, on the aspx backend have the function's results returned to as string and then set the contents

```
Dim tblPayDetails As Table = DoSomething()
placePayDetails.Controls.Add(tblPayDetails)
```